# Perimeter or Calculus Word problem

Tags: calculus, geometry

> A rectangular plot of farmland will be bounded on one side by a river
>   and on the other three sides by a single strand of electric fence.
>   With 1400m of wire at your disposal, what is the largest area you can
>   enclose, and what are its dimensions?

Is there a way to solve this without Calculus? This sounds like a simple perimeter problem. If you have to use Calculus to solve this, how would I start? Could someone show me the steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r$ be the length of the rectangle along the river and $s$ be the length of the other side. Thus, we have to:

Max $rs$

Subject to:

$r + 2s = 1400$

Substitute for $r$ back into the objective function and we get the problem reformulated as:

Max $(1400-2s) s$

You can find the value of $s$ either via calculus or by completing the square.

Comment: Good to know this can be done algebraically as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can solve this without calculus by a process called **quadratic optimisation** (though the math behind it really uses calculus, you can do it without taking a single derivative or integral).

The plot is rectangular, so we have four sides which sum to 1400: $x + 2z = 1400$
Area $A = x \cdot z$
We'll want to state $A$ in terms of x only, so we use a simultaneous equation. Rearrange $x + 2z = 1400$ to form $2z = 1400 - x$, simplify to $z = 700 - \frac{x}{2}$
Plug that into the area equation:
$A = x \cdot (700 - \frac{x}{2})$
$A = 700x - \frac{x^{2}}{2}$
Now we have a quadratic, so we can optimise it. (If we wanted to use calculus, we could see where the derivative is equal to 0, but we won't do that.) We will do this by **finding the vertex of the quadratic.**

We'll want the $a,b,c$ values of our quadratic in form ($ax^{2} + bx + c$):
$a = \frac{-1}{2}$
$b = 700$
$c = 0$

To find the x-value of the vertex, we use the formula $x=\frac{-b}{2a}$:
 $x=\frac{-700}{2\frac{-1}{2}}$
 $x=\frac{-700}{\frac{-2}{2}}$
 $x=\frac{-700}{-1}$
 $x=700$

We just plug that in to find the A-value:
$A = 700x - \frac{x^{2}}{2}$
$x=700$
$A = 700(700) - \frac{700^{2}}{2}$
$A = 245000$

This only leaves the question of what the length of the other 2 sides is. If $x + 2z = 1400$, and $x = 700$, then $z = 350.$

So there's the answer: The area is maximised (to 245000) when one side is 700 units long, and the other two sides are 350 each.

Comment: Interesting approach. I just graphed ended up graphing the parabola and finding the vertex.

Comment: If you have a calculator, you can do that once you have $A = 700x - \frac{x^2}{2}$, sure. Just make sure you know how to actually do it, as opposed to knowing how to use the *trace* function.